# Where to upload console app for Azure DF v2 custom activity?

Tags: custom-activity, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create DF v2 custom activity. I have console application, but i am not sure where to put it.
Should i only build it and upload to blob storage or is there some special publishment?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

As stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity you need to upload your code to a Compute Environment which will be an Azure Batch pool.

> The custom activity runs your customized code logic on an Azure Batch
>   pool of virtual machines.

Then just configure the linked service and the activity as shown in the official documentation.

Hope this helped!